# Does Google Pubsub Push subscriptions support HMAC authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, subscription

For managing webhooks for project, we would like to use google pubsub push subscriptions, but could not find enough information whether HMAC authentication are supported or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HMAC authentication is not supported.

Google Cloud Pub/Sub authentication require an OAuth 2.0 Access Token or a Signed JWT.

OAuth 2.0 Access tokens represent a principal derived from either a service account or a user.

Signed JWTs are created by signing a JWT using a service account's RSA private key (which also represents a principal).